# How to hide typeinfo in gdb output

Tags: c++, templates, gdb

i am debugging heavy templated code and looking for a way to hide the type information in the backtrace and while printing variables.
It would be even better if you could hide only the template arguments, since they make the backtrace very hard to read.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method would be to use gdb plugins. I don't know of a native setting in gdb (except frame filters) that can achieve the desired results.

Do look into https://github.com/tromey/gdb-helpers, more specifically https://github.com/philtweir/gdb-pretty-frame-cpp. I have used **gdb-pretty-frame** with custom template heavy code.